# Creating a subset of data frame using condition in python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, subset

suppose I have this data frame I want to create a subset of it based on the conditions below.

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'file':[1205,2897,1205,1205,4312,1322,1242,52,2897,111],
                         'department':[finance,finance,IT,marketing,marketing,IT,finance,IT,marketing,IT],
                         'status':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                         })
```

```
   file department  status
0   1205    finance       1
1   2897    finance       1
2   1205       IT         1
3   1205    marketing     1
4   4312    marketing     1
5   1322       IT         1
6   1242    finance       1
7   52         IT         1
8   2897    marketing     1
9   111        IT         1
```

- if the file exist in **finance** and exist in **IT** delete it from
  **finance** and keep it in **IT**
- if the file exist in **finance** and **marketing** and **IT** REMOVE
  FROM FIRST 2 AND KEEP IT IN **IT**
- if the file exist in **finance** and **marketing** delete from the
  first and keep it in the **marketing**
- if the file exist in **marketing** and **IT** delete from the
  first and keep it in the **IT**

THE EXPECTED RESULT :

```
   file department  status
0   1205       IT         1
1   2897    marketing     1
2   4312    marketing     1
3   1322       IT         1
4   1242    finance       1
5   52         IT         1
6   111        IT         1
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `CategoricalDtype` to create an ordered collection such as `'finance' < 'marketing' < 'IT'`:

```
cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(['finance', 'marketing', 'IT'], ordered=True)
out = (df.astype({'department': cat}).sort_values('department')
         .drop_duplicates('file', keep='last').sort_index())
print(out)

# Output
   file department  status
2  1205         IT       1
4  4312  marketing       1
5  1322         IT       1
6  1242    finance       1
7    52         IT       1
8  2897  marketing       1
9   111         IT       1
```

Comment: Instead of `.drop_duplicates('file', keep='last')` would `.groupby('file').last()` work as well?  Specifically, does `groupby()` preserve row order?

Comment: @jch. You have to also `sort_values` before `groupby` if you want to take the `last` values or use `max` instead.

Comment: @khaledM_dev. Does it solve your problem?